# Muddle related to “boy-or-girl paradox”

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a species of frog such that just one clue permits you to sex its individuals: the fact that only males can croak, although they almost never do. If you collect two individuals and happen to observe one of them croaking, then you can be certain the croaker is male, but since you have no information about the other frog you will presumably say that it is equally likely to be male or female. (Actually you do have a little information: the frog is slightly likelier to be female since it had a chance to croak and didn’t, but let’s assume the error is negligible.)

This much seems fairly uncontroversial, and we can re-formulate our little conclusion in the statement that, if you have two frogs and you observe one of them croaking, there is probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of there being a female in the pair.

But what if you collect two specimens and then, while your back is turned, you hear a single croak come from one of the frogs? What has changed in this case is only that you cannot now point to one of the frogs and say, “This one is certainly male and the other one I have no information about.” Nevertheless there is still a frog (the croaker) who is definitely known to be male and another (the noncroaker) about whom nothing is known. Consequently the probability of a female in the pair is still $\frac{1}{2}$.

LATER: If we insist on distinguishing the frogs by a visible criterion (left versus right rather than the more natural croaker versus noncroaker) then we have the following argument: $(1)$ if the croaker is on the left then the frog on the right is equally likely to be male or female; and $(2)$ if the croaker is on the right than the frog on the left is equally likely to be male or female; therefore $(3)$ whichever frog is the croaker, the other one is equally likely to be male or female. To be explicit, we have the following equally likely alternatives:

$1)$ croaker on the left, noncroaking male on the right

$2)$ croaker on the right, noncroaking male on the left

$3)$ croaker on the left, female on the right

$4)$ croaker on the right, female on the left

TO RESUME: Now suppose there is another species of frog such that just one clue permits you to sex its individuals: fights are almost unknown in this species, but when a fight does occur there is always a male combattant. You collect two individuals of this species and happen to observe a fight. You now know that the frogs are not both females, but what is the probability that one of them is female? The argument of the previous cases doesn’t seem to go through. It might be argued that, since what you learn from the fight is exactly the fact that the frogs are not both female, the remaining possibilities (two males/a male on the left and a female on the right/a male on the right and a female on the left) should be considered equally probable, so that in this case the probability of a female in the pair is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Can these conclusions be right? And if not, where does the reasoning go wrong? Thanks if you can help.

Peace,
Sean

Comment: "when a fight does occur there is always a male combattant". OK, but is the fight more likely to occur when there are two male frogs together than when there is just one male frog and a female frog? Or are the male and female equally likely to fight as the two males? I am having a hard time imagining the mechanism that would support an "equally likely" probability.

Comment: I agree with you about the implausibility of that mechanism, but nonetheless the “equally likely” hypothesis is the one I was trying to get across. What’s needed is some kind of test that the puzzle solver can accept as a black box. Unfortunately I can’t think of anything like that.

Comment: How about this mechanism: a fight occurs because one frog instigates it. A male frog has a 1/1000 chance to instigate a fight. A female frog also has 1/1000 chance to instigate a fight, but only in the presence of male pheromones. Two female frogs, no male pheromones, no fight. But either two male frogs or one male and one female gives you two frogs who each have 1/1000 chance to start a fight. Fights are just as likely with MF as with MM, likewise FM.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) on the boy or girl paradox?

> Nevertheless there is still a frog (the croaker) who is definitely known to be male and another (the noncroaker) about whom nothing is known. Consequently the probability of a female in the pair is still 1/2.

This is incorrect; the probability of a female in the pair is $\frac{2}{3}$ as in your second argument, because as in your second argument all you've learned is that of the four possibilities MM, MF, FM, FF (which started out equally likely) you've excluded the last one.

Intuitively you might say that the issue is that there are two possible croakers, and in the first possibility MM you don't know which of the two males is "the" croaker. The $\frac{1}{2}$ comes in some sense from assigning the MM case double the weight it should have.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where my reasoning is going off the rails? I put an addendum in the original post because I didn’t have room in this comment.

Comment: @sean: the four possibilities you describe are not equally likely, although as in the Wikipedia article on the boy-or-girl paradox there is room for ambiguity here. One issue is that there are too many $\frac{1}{2}$ves running around in this problem; if you change the prior distribution of genders so that males occur with an initial probability of $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$ then you're forced to be clearer about what's going on. Then the four possibilities MM, MF, FM, FF have prior probabilities $p^2, p(1-p), (1-p)p, (1-p)^2$ respectively and, again, hearing a croak eliminates the last only.

Comment: If male frogs rarely croak, but they croak independently of each other, you are nearly twice as likely to hear a croak during a brief period of observation in the MM case as in the MF case. Hence I think the MM case *should* have double the weight of the MF case, and likewise double the weight of the FM case. Or to put it another way, out of every four croaks from randomly-selected pairs of frogs, on average two will come from MM pairs.

Comment: @David: that's true but it doesn't affect what happens if you only condition on hearing a single croak. The point of the hypothesis that croaks are very rare is that we are not updating on the observation that we don't hear croaks at any given time. Your observation would make sense if croaks followed, say, some kind of Poisson process, but we aren't told that here. In the Poisson model it would be true that the longer we went without hearing a croak the more likely it is that our frogs are female but here we aren't told anything whatsoever about how croaks are generated.

Comment: If it's true that two of every four croaks come from random pairs of frogs come from MM pairs, then I say it most certainly *does* say something about what happens if you only condition on hearing a single croak. That two out of four could come from a Poisson process or from the fact that 1% of male frogs croak once an hour like clockwork (but each at its own time past the hour) or each male frog croaks once every 100 hours like clockwork, or any other mechanism as long as you have independence between frogs.

Comment: Here's a mechanism that matches the setup for the boy-girl paradox. All male frogs croak constantly. But since you are deaf, you rely on a phone app to detect croaking. The app only says "I hear croaking" or "I don't hear croaking"--it doesn't indicate which frog or how many frogs croaked. So it will say "I hear croaking" in 100% of MM, MF, and FM cases, and 0% of FF cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a male frog is observed to croak with probability c and a female frog is observed to croak with probability zero. Then the probability of a female in the pair, given that exactly one frog is heard to croak, is 1/(2-c). Now assume a pair of frogs is observed to fight with probability f if a male is in the pair and with probability zero if no male is in the pair. Then the probability of a female in the pair, given that a fight is observed, is 2/3.

The take-home lesson, I now think, is that the first task in solving a probability puzzle should always be to turn the puzzle into a sensible question, no matter how many unwarranted assumptions you need to make along the way. Do NOT try to “honour” the ambiguity of vague information by treating it “with a light hand” and hoping that the inferences you draw from it are valid on any of its possible interpretations: that way leads to paradox.